# ./manage.py test results in django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: MyNewColumn

Tags: python, django, testing, migration

Long story short: I made tests.py to cover my django code, I modified code and models a lot (18 migrations) and everything was OK.

But after last change and migration (Added some Boolean fileds) my tests start crashing on the 8th migration with

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: tickets_ticket.ActionRequired
```

In Apache on web site I can use the new column, add models with it and everything looks nice, but tests fails

Can somebody please tell me, what went wrong and how to correct it?

---

The long story:

Models.py:

```
def Ticket_generateUniqueID(related=''):
    retval=''
    sanitized=''
......
    # --- now find unique value
    while True:
            passNo += 1
            retval = generateID()
            try:
                    t = Ticket.objects.get(ticket_number=retval)
                    pass
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    return retval
....
class Ticket(models.Model):
....
    ticket_number = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=Ticket_generateUniqueID,help_text=u"ID of ticket")
    ActionRequired = models.BooleanField(default=False,help_text=u"Action Required")
    def save(self):  # {{{
        if not self.id and not self.ticket_number: self.ticket_number=Ticket_generateUniqueID('OTH')
        retval=super(Ticket,self).save()
        return retval
```

and my testing session (should start with no test_* database)

```
$ ./manage.py test -v3
settings ...
Creating test database for alias 'default' (':memory:')...
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: django_extensions
  Apply all migrations: admin, tickets, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
Running pre-migrate handlers for application admin
Running pre-migrate handlers for application auth
Running pre-migrate handlers for application contenttypes
Running pre-migrate handlers for application sessions
Running pre-migrate handlers for application django_extensions
Running pre-migrate handlers for application tickets
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Loading 'initial_data' fixtures...
Checking '/home/gilhad/GIT/kompitech_test/src/kompitech_test' for fixtures...
No fixture 'initial_data' in '/home/gilhad/GIT/kompitech_test/src/kompitech_test'.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying tickets.0001_initial... OK
  Applying tickets.0002_importedemail_is_new... OK
  Applying tickets.0003_auto_20151102_1642... OK
  Applying tickets.0004_auto_20151116_1633... OK
  Applying tickets.0005_auto_20151118_0756... OK
  Applying tickets.0006_emailpart_originalfilename... OK
  Applying tickets.0007_ticket_fv_ticket_id... OK
  Applying tickets.0008_auto_20151123_1430...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 50, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 71, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 88, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 147, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 109, in setup_databases
    return setup_databases(self.verbosity, self.interactive, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 299, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 377, in create_test_db
    test_flush=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 115, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 68, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 102, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 108, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 139, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 457, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type, old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 202, in _alter_field
    self._remake_table(model, alter_fields=[(old_field, new_field)])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 139, in _remake_table
    self.create_model(temp_model)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 213, in create_model
    definition, extra_params = self.column_sql(model, field)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 125, in column_sql
    default_value = self.effective_default(field)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 175, in effective_default
    default = field.get_default()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 719, in get_default
    return self.default()
  File "/home/gilhad/GIT/kompitech_test/src/kompitech_test/tickets/models.py", line 56, in Ticket_generateUniqueID
    t = Ticket.objects.get(ticket_number=retval)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 351, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 122, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 966, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 265, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 700, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 485, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: tickets_ticket.ActionRequired
```

see, that it is not nearly the last migration and tests went as expexted before everytime

```
$ ls -1 tickets/migrations/*py
tickets/migrations/0001_initial.py
tickets/migrations/0002_importedemail_is_new.py
tickets/migrations/0003_auto_20151102_1642.py
tickets/migrations/0004_auto_20151116_1633.py
tickets/migrations/0005_auto_20151118_0756.py
tickets/migrations/0006_emailpart_originalfilename.py
tickets/migrations/0007_ticket_fv_ticket_id.py
tickets/migrations/0008_auto_20151123_1430.py
tickets/migrations/0009_auto_20151123_1718.py
tickets/migrations/0010_auto_20151123_1928.py
tickets/migrations/0011_auto_20151124_0938.py
tickets/migrations/0012_auto_20151125_1351.py
tickets/migrations/0013_auto_20151125_1406.py
tickets/migrations/0014_configemailcompany.py
tickets/migrations/0015_auto_20151126_1435.py
tickets/migrations/0016_configemailcompany_we.py
tickets/migrations/0017_auto_20151126_1730.py
tickets/migrations/0018_auto_20151127_1103.py
tickets/migrations/0019_auto_20151130_0934.py
tickets/migrations/__init__.py
```

The failing migration:

```
migrations.AlterField(
    model_name='ticket',
    name='by_user',
    field=models.ForeignKey(related_name='changed_records_of_ticket', blank=True, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, help_text='Last modification was by this user (autofilled)', null=True, db_index=False),
    preserve_default=True,
    ),
migrations.AlterField(
    model_name='ticket',
    name='ticket_number',
    field=models.CharField(default=tickets.models.Ticket_generateUniqueID, help_text='ID of ticket', max_length=100),
    preserve_default=True,
   ),
```

(and lot of other by_user changes in other models)

Comment: What is the content of the migration that is failing?

Comment: added it to question

Comment: @Mondongo I Know, but there are two kind of fields - one normal - common for all instancies (like ticket_number) and then some special, which are used just in some cases, depending from where what data obtained (and thuse are CamelCase to recognise them on first look, like that ActionRequired)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `Ticket_generateUniqueID` method used to get the default value is attempting to fetch a column that the migration has not created yet.

```
try:
    t = Ticket.objects.get(ticket_number=retval)
    pass
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    return retval
```

In this case, I think you can avoid the problem by changing your method to use `exists()` instead of `get()`.

```
if Ticket.objects.filter(ticket_number=retval).exists():
    pass
else:
    return retval
```

If it wasn't possible to rewrite the default method, then it would be trickier to fix. I believe that you would have to add a data migration *before* the migration that is causing the errors, and set the field values there. In the data migration, you could use `Ticket = apps.get_model('myapp', 'Ticket')`. You would then be able to run `Ticket.objects.get()` without any errors.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem completly :) Ran 419 tests in 33.381s
:)

Answer (score 0):

Just one update: when I deleted all migrations and recreated them as one simple, my tests starts to fail with:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: tickets_ticket
```

as my tests created (and not saved) Ticket objects before loading fixture with data so I added this sanity test before the while cycle:

```
if not( u'tickets_ticket' in connection.introspection.table_names()):
    return generateID() # if no table exists, none ID exists too, so anything is unique :)
# --- now find unique value
```